# Apache Camel - Prevent Exchange Propagation on Route Policy on Exception

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-dsl

I'm currently working on an application which uses Camel heavily. I'll briefly explain what I'm trying to achieve:

An OnException Processor (handled=true) catches an Exception and when that happens I want to stop the Exchange from being processed by the RoutePolicy(s) of the route. Example with pseudo-code:

```
<route id="route1" routePolicyRef="policy1, policy2, policy3">
    ... an exception *e1* is thrown... 
</route>

<onException>
    <handled>true</handled>
    ... handle exception *e1*
    <bean ref="customExceptionProcessor"/>
</onException>
```

So in essence, once an Exception is *handled* I want the Exchange to stop propagating to all the attached Policy(s).

Wondering if there's a simple way to achieve this which I may have missed when reading from the documentation.

That's it really. Cheers.

Comment: Are you ok with the propagation stopping completely? That is, the exchange stops. In that case try <stop>.

Comment: Hi Souciance, I should have mentioned I have tried that already although making use of the exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, true). I'll try <stop/> straight in the spring dsl after my processor finishes.